# Photos not uploading to One Drive

Tags: onedrive, photos

My 8.1 phone has OneDrive turned one and configured to upload photo's Best Quality (Needs Wi-Fi) but nothing is being uploaded and synchronized.  What else needs to be conigured or is this feature broken?

Comment: Just to be sure, is the phone actually connected to a WiFi network? Can you otherwise access OneDrive from the phone? Can you upload photos manually (by choosing Share -> OneDrive)? And have you taken any new photos since enabling the backup? Because I don't think it'll retroactively upload existing photos.

Comment: Yes I am connected to wi-fi. I have a ton of photo's since it was turned on but none uploading.  I would be bummed if it won't retroactively synchronize because I have a LOT of them to get backed up.

Comment: @ChiliYago - It might be a good thing that you can't use OneDrive. Did you read the Terms of Service? They are obscene. I'm trying to figure out how to remove it from my device because the terms are so perverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try tapping "..." to extend the menu and tap on "upload status". See if there are any errors or pending uploads.

You can also "select all" and "share" -> "OneDrive".

Hope that helps.